# Thread can only be started once error in Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am creating a client web socket that connects to a server.
And I am starting the connection using a Tkinter gui button. To prevent gui from getting stuck I am using threading. My client disconnects from the server after some time. So when I try to connect again using the button it shows an error that a Thread can only be started once.

My code for Button and client method:

```
async def start_client(url, duration):
    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
        start_time = time.time()
        while time.time() - start_time < duration:
            message = await ws.recv()
            msg = json.loads(message)
            print(msg)

            if 'timestamp android.sensor.accelerometer' in msg:
                write_acc(msg)
            else:
                write_gyro(msg)



def on_click():
    initial_setup_files()
    asyncio.run(start_client(url, 4))
    final_csv_file_creator()
    print("Disconnected from the server")




btn = Button(window,
             text="Start Server ",
             fg="black",
             bg="cyan",
             font=("Times New Roman", 30, 'bold'),
             command=threading.Thread(target=on_click).start
             )
btn.pack(padx=20,
         pady=20)
```

[image: Error]

I was expecting that client connects again without errors

Comment: Change `command=threading.Thread(target=on_click).start` to `command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=on_click).start()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression creates a new `Thread` object, and then it creates and returns a new *functional object* whose `__call__` method starts the new thread:

```py
threading.Thread(target=on_click).start
```

You can call the functional object any number of times, but every time you call it, it tries to start the *same* thread. That's not allowed. It's just like the error message says. A `Thread` object may only be started one time.

When you said, `command=threading.Thread(target=on_click).start`, you're giving the `Button` a `command` that tries to start the same thread again and again. You need to provide a `command` that starts a new thread every time.

The most obvious way (in my *personal* opinion) is to declare another function:

```
def handle_button_press():
    threading.Thread(target=on_click).start()

btn = Button(window,
             text="Start Server ",
             fg="black",
             bg="cyan",
             font=("Times New Roman", 30, 'bold'),
             command=handle_button_press
             )
```

---

But, you can also do what @TheLizard said in a comment. `lambda:threading.Thread(target=on_click).start()` also is an expression that returns a new functional object. But, the difference is, its `__call__` method creates a new `Thread` every time—creates and then starts it. Specifically, it's `__call__` method does this:

```
threading.Thread(target=on_click).start()
```